# Alguien me puede explicar como saco 6 si las reglas no me dejan?

Tags: c#

Alguien me puede explicar como llego a la conclusion de que F(6)=2 si en las reglas dicen que al ser par se debe multiplicar por 2. Segun lo que entendi la cosa va asi:

- f(7)=1[+2]=3[+2]=5[+2]=**7**  [+2] por que 7 es impar(odd)
- f(6)=1[*2]=2[*2]=4[*2]=**8** [ERROR]  [*2] por que 6 es par (even)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: Creo que esto deberías preguntarlo en el sitio de Matemáticas de StackOverflow, saludos.